# Datalabels no se muestran correctamente - ApexCharts

Tags: apex-chart

Buen dia, alguno de ustedes sabra porque algunos puntos de la grafica no se muestran ya que tambien contienen datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar los circulos vacios son los que no se muestran los datalabels y esos si tienen valor. Estoy utilizando el siguiente codigo. De antemano gracias.

```
                       // Colocar puntos de referencia en los picos de la grafica
                        markers: {
                            size: 8,
                            colors: ["#FFFFFF"],
                            strokeColor: "#006EFF",
                            strokeWidth: 3
                        },
                        // Textos que van adentro de la barra
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            //formatter: function (val, opts) {
                            //  return "Q. " + val
                            //},
                            //formatter: function (value) {
                            //  return value ;
                            //},
                            formatter: function (val, opts) {
                                return new Intl.NumberFormat('es-GT', {
                                    style: 'currency',
                                    currency: 'GTQ',
                                }).format(val);
                            },
                            //offsetY: -20,
                            style: {
                                fontSize: '14px',
                                /*colors: ["#fff"],*/
                                fontFamily: 'Plus Jakarta Sans, sans-serif',
                            }
                        },
```